# Parseint – truncating with e+

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, numbers, hex, parseint

I am using `parseInt()` internally to convert a value that I now want to convert to another number system with `toString()`.

```
parseInt(value, 10).toString(16)
```

But since the integer is being truncated (ie `1.7956279830335669e+47`) because of length, I am unable to achieve the desired hexadecimal representation of my number.

Is there some other way to cast a string to an int?
How can I go about resolving this?

Comment: Use `Number` instead? `Number('1.7956279830335669e+47')` . Or which value is `1.7956279830335669e+47` ?

Comment: https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/09/javascript-bigint.html  which support hex as well

Comment: @FelixKling, the number returned by parse int, it now is truncated with the e+

Comment: What's the  value of `value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```
BigInt(value).toString();
```

You need it because the largest `Number` JavaScript can support is `9007199254740991`:

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

You can use `BigInt` because it's a built-in global object, however it's not a fully supported ECMAScript feature - currently it's in Stage 3 of development.

Comment: Can you link to the library as well? Also elaborating on why they should use it is helpful for any future visitor.

Comment: Yes sorry @FelixKling.

Answer (score 1):

Try (works on chrome where BigInt is supported)

```
BigInt(Number(value)).toString(16);
```

however using this approach we loose precision but we can use alternative approach by convert number in exponential form to integer form

```js
let value= "1.7956279830335669e+47";

let sim    = BigInt(Number(value)).toString(16);
let prec   = BigInt(fix2IntStr(value)).toString(16);
let direct = 179562798303356690000000000000000000000000000000n.toString(16);


// convert "exponential" form to integer string
function fix2IntStr(str) { 
  let [m,e] = value.split('e');
  e = e - (m.length - m.indexOf('.')-1);
  m = m.replace('.','');
  return m+"0".repeat(e);
}

console.log('simple :', sim);
console.log('precise:',prec);
console.log('direct :',direct);
```

Comment: I'd assume the original value is not actually `"1.7956279830335669e+47"`. Using `Number(value)` will still loose precision.